# Cookie not appended in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, web, cookies

I try to add cookies to the response in a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application. The issue is that the cookie is not appended to the response.This is the code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!\n");

                string cookieValueFromContext = context.Request.Cookies["hello"];

                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Response: {cookieValueFromContext}");

                context.Response.Cookies.Append("hello", "cookie", new CookieOptions
                {
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(10),
                    IsEssential = true

                });

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Ending");
            });

        });

       
    }
```

And this is what I see in browser:

[image]

I tried to debug the application the debug stops at the append cookie method, no exception is raised. Message `Ending` is not displayed. In browser (Chrome) no cookie is stored, I checked Application/Cookies, not even after reload. From my knowledge I do not need to add Cookie Policy Option if the cookie is set as essential. From what I read on other posts the browser might choose which cookies to consider essential, even if you set it as essential. Could this be the case ?

Comment: I added a try/catch around append function and this is the error that I receive:
Exception : The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.ThrowIfReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.set_Item(String key, StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ResponseCookies.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
   at WebApplication1.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__1_2>d.MoveNext()

Does anyone know what the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

After I appended cookies to the response, the cookies were not appended in the response and they were not added into the cookies database in Chrome. The issue is that after the ASP.NET Core writes in the body of the response, it does not write anymore in the headers.So, I had a previous middleware on another endpoint that was writing a string to the body of the message, and even if the cookies endpoint was different, they were still not written in the header becouse of the previous middleware that was writing data in the body of the response.Another issue is that the append method did not throw an exception in Visual Studio, it just stoped at the appending cookies part. I had to add a try/catch in order to see the exception: the response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started. After I deleted all middlewares and left only the append cookie method,it worked.So it is to be noted that all the headers modifications must be made in the beggining of the middleware pipeline before the response is written in the body of the response.